# Using Securimage captcha with Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

I installed a laravel package for securimage captcha, everything seems to be fine(as in it show the random captcha), but even after putting the correct text, it still says invalid.
can someone help me please.
Here is my code

```
Route::any('/test-captcha', function (){
    if (Request::getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $rules = ['captcha' => 'required|captcha'];

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            echo '<p style="color: #ff0000;">Incorrect!</p>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<p style="color: #00ff30;">Matched :)</p>';
        }
    }

    $form = '<form method="post" action="test-captcha">';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="' . csrf_token() . '">';
    $form .= '<p>' . captcha_img() . '</p>';
    $form .= '<p><button type="submit" name="check">Check</button></p>';
    $form .= '</form>';
    return $form;
});
```

Comment: What version of secureimage captcha you are using?

Comment: Am using Version 0.1.3

Comment: There is one possible, the session is not working properly. The generated code is saved into session by default. What session driver you are using?

Comment: Am using   file session driver

Comment: following the docs under https://packagist.org/packages/yhbyun/laravel-securimage you have to add the service provider as well. don't forget to clear the clear the compiled cache.

Comment: are sessions working properly? check session cookie, if for every request a new session cookie value is generated then there is some problem with sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short resolution: 
Add this lines to your routes.php file:

```
Route::get('securimage', ['as' => 'securimage', 'uses' => '\Yhbyun\Securimage\SecurimageController@getCaptcha']);

Route::get('securimage/audio', ['as' => 'securimage.audio', 'uses' => '\Yhbyun\Securimage\SecurimageController@getAudio']);

Route::get('securimage/check', ['as' => 'securimage.check', 'uses' => '\Yhbyun\Securimage\SecurimageController@check']);
```

### Here i will explain, why

The Problem in this case is, that the package defines its routes in
 **/vendor/yhbyun/laravel-securimage/src/SecurimageServiceProvider.php**  like this:

```
        $app['router']->get('securimage', ['as' => 'securimage', 'uses' => 'Yhbyun\Securimage\SecurimageController@getCaptcha']);

        $app['router']->get('securimage/audio', ['as' => 'securimage.audio', 'uses' => 'Yhbyun\Securimage\SecurimageController@getAudio']);

        $app['router']->get('securimage/check', ['as' => 'securimage.check', 'uses' => 'Yhbyun\Securimage\SecurimageController@check']);
```

If you run `php artisan route:list` you can see that there is no middleware applied, since In Laravel's Kernel.php file only the routes defined in routes.php are grouped with the 'web' middleware applied :

```
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
```

The web middleware group contains the Middleware for Starting Sessions:

```
    'web' => [
        // ....
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // .....
    ],
```

Maybe someone wants to create a pull request for the Laravel Versions that already use the 'web' middleware. This could be something like (inside SecurimageServiceProvider.php) :

```
    $app['router']->group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() use ($app) {
        $app['router']->get('securimage', ['as' => 'securimage', 'uses' => 'Yhbyun\Securimage\SecurimageController@getCaptcha']);

        $app['router']->get('securimage/audio', ['as' => 'securimage.audio', 'uses' => 'Yhbyun\Securimage\SecurimageController@getAudio']);

        $app['router']->get('securimage/check', ['as' => 'securimage.check', 'uses' => 'Yhbyun\Securimage\SecurimageController@check']);
    });
```